# How to use custom view controller in UISearchController for results?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, search, uisearchcontroller

I am currently trying to implement search feature for an app. The goal is to display the search results in a different view controller. What I mean exactly is this:

`UISearchController(searchResultsController: myCustomViewControllerHere)`

All the answers I found along with tutorial uses the current view controller with data as the view controller that displays the results as such:

`UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`

Can someone please help out on how to do this? I'm linking a tutorial where it show the results on the same VC

[Tutorial Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Check out the Apple's Documentation. You can easily find a sample code from there.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create an SearchController and set it up to show the results in another TableViewController:

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    var controladorDeBusca: UISearchController!

    var resultsTableViewController: ResultsTableViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        resultsTableViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "resultsTableViewController") as? ResultsTableViewController

        configurarControladorDeBusca()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func configurarControladorDeBusca() {

        controladorDeBusca = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableViewController)
        controladorDeBusca.delegate = self
        controladorDeBusca.searchResultsUpdater = resultsTableViewController
        controladorDeBusca.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        definesPresentationContext = true

        controladorDeBusca.loadViewIfNeeded()

        //Configura a barra do Controlador de busca
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.delegate = resultsTableViewController
        controladorDeBusca.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.placeholder = "Search place"
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.barTintColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.tintColor = self.view.tintColor

        //Adiciona a barra do Controlador de Busca a barra do navegador
        navigationItem.titleView = controladorDeBusca.searchBar
    }
}
```

ResultsTableViewController

```
import UIKit

class ResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var array = ["Brazil", "Bolivia", "United States", "Canada", "England", "Germany", "France", "Portugal"]

    var arrayFilter = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arrayFilter.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = arrayFilter[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {


    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        arrayFilter.removeAll()

        if let text = searchBar.text {
            for string in array {
                if string.contains(text) {
                    arrayFilter.append(string)
                }
            }
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        arrayFilter.removeAll()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

        arrayFilter.removeAll()
        tableView.reloadData()

        return true
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping. Im a bit confused though. How do I get the filtered data to display on "ResultadoBuscaLocaisTableViewController" ? Do I pass the data there somehow?

Comment: Using the updateSearchResults and reloading the data in the tableView

Comment: My whole vode is to big to paste here

Comment: Can you send a link to it then? I don't know how to make "ResultadoBuscaLocaisTableViewController" responsible for the data shown. I also do not know if it has to do with delegates etc? Thanks!

Comment: Here. I posted the hole `ResultadoBuscaLocaisTableViewController` class.

Comment: Actually it doesnt work. I cant get anything to show on my second view controller. The Table does not load or anything.

Comment: It works fine for me. To show the results you need to have something like an array to save the results and use its data to populate the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164413/discussion-between-user7097242-and-guidupas).

Comment: There were 2 lines of code missing, sorry about that. I edited it and now it is correct.

Comment: These `var resultsTableViewController: ResultsTableViewController?` and `resultsTableViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "resultsTableViewController") as? ResultsTableViewController` in the ViewController

Comment: I doing get it. Why are you instantiating a view controller there? Is there even a great way to do this? seems a bit off? How do you keep populating the tableview as you type and not just when you are finished?

Comment: You need to instantiate it because you have to set up these lines `controladorDeBusca = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableViewController)`, `controladorDeBusca.searchResultsUpdater = resultsTableViewController` and `controladorDeBusca.searchBar.delegate = resultsTableViewController`. Otherwise the search controller can't know how to act.

Comment: Ok how do you change the greyish background to an image or a different color when you begin to search?

Comment: @GuiDupas thank you for the explanation. I'm also trying to understand once I select an item in the result view controller, how do I remove it from the screen and return to the original one. I tried using a regular seague but it caused the original screen to push on top of the result screen instead. thank you